# Artificial magnetic field generator for Mars

Tags: terraforming, planets

Following the question asked here :

[Artificial volcanos on Mars to recover its atmosphere](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/11159/artificial-volcanos-on-mars-to-recover-its-atmosphere)

Would it be too hard to create an artificial magnetic field around Mars ?

Place a coil on each of the poles and turn them on, how much energy would it take to generate a magnetic field big enough to deter the cosmic radiation and solar wind ?

I believe this would cool down the outer layers of atmosphere and prevent its escape from the gravity of mars, slowing the rate at wich Mars loses its atmosphere.

Would two coils be enough to create a magnetic circuit around the planet ? Would the mass of the planet between the poles prevent (or create too much resistence) for the magnetic circuit ? Would it consume too much power to generate that field ?

Comment: Revival of mars magnetoshpere was asked: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/8832/what-would-be-best-way-to-re-melt-mars-mantle-and-core-to-revive-its-magnetosph

Comment: I mean I asked different question but revival magnetosphere by supercooled magnets was the best solution. Check it, see if it answers your question

Comment: Fits perfectly.

Comment: OK go ahead and add some love to that answer - it received very little. :-)